# Is there anyway to use a rectangular area as a geofence?

Tags: android

Actually, I'm trying to build an app for my college project using Android Studio. Basically, the motive is to create a virtual boundary around the college and when the user enters the boundary, it will notify the user that it has entered the college and he will be marked present in the database.

I've able to mark the rectangular boundary around my college on the map, but I'm unable to link that marked area as a geofence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can specify a rectangular geofence.  You can only specify the center and radius of a geofence circle.  But, if you can determine the lat/lon of the center of your campus, and determine the distance between, say, the lower left corner and the upper right corner of the campus (then divide by 2 to get the radius).  You can set the geofence to be a circle that surrounds the four corners of your campus.  When entering the circle from the side, front or back, you may alert slightly before you get to the campus rectangle, but at least your campus would all be covered.

Or, you could not use geofencing at all, and just use the Polygon.Contains() method to see if the current lat/lon is contained within the rectangle:

```
Point point = new Point(currentLat, currentLon);
boolean contains = polygon.contains(point);
```

Comment: I guess the first solution will work, but can I add any pending intent using Polygon.Contains() method, to get the notification if the user is inside the area ?

Comment: Well, you can have the location manager constantly getting location updates, and with every update, you can check if the polygon that defines your campus contains the user's lat/lon, then raise your own notification.  You would probably just want an on-screen notification, rather than an alert, as your location change event will probably fire a lot, but that will definitely work.